# SQL Join left join or left outer join

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I am having a question in SQL Joins. I have table employee with employeeid as primary key and some other columns for employee. And there is another table called employeeaddress where there can be multiple employeeid is a foreign key. One employee can have many employeeaddresses just to explain one to many relationship.

If I want to write a query which will fetch the following columns

```
 employee.employeeid, employee.empname,
 employeeaddress.employeeaddressid, employeeaddress.addr1,
 employeeaddress.addr2
```

So there can be an employee with no employeeaddress. But anyway I wanted to fetch all the employees who may have zero or multiple addresses.

Do I need to apply `left join` or `left outer join`? I want the following result for a table that has 2 employees `John` and `Michael` where `John` has two `employeeaddresses` with `employeeaddressid 21` and `22` and `Michael` has no `employeeaddress`

```
1, John, 21, addr1 for John, addr2 for John
1, John, 22, another addr1 for John, another addr2 for John
2, Michael, NULL , NULL , NULL
```

The above result is arranged in the following fashion

```
employee.employeeid, employee.empname, employeeaddress.employeeaddressid, employeeaddress.addr1, employeeaddress.addr2
```

Please help.

Comment: LEFT JOIN is the same as LEFT OUTER JOIN. How does your current query look?

Comment: I used the LEFT join only for my query but since I fetch multiple columns I am still validating whether the primary key in the first table gets repeated for multiple entries in the second table. So thats why I explained my query using a simple scenario

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN but... address1 and address2 are two different columns of the same row in emplyeeaddress table? Or do you want flat two different rows?

Comment: @JoeTaras address1 and address2 are two different columns of the same row in employeeaddress table

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description it sounds like you're looking for a query as follows.  If you also wanted the address details, you'll just have to add a left join to the outer query.

Also, as comments have eluded to, `LEFT JOIN` is shorthand for `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, they will produce the same results.

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
inner join
(
    SELECT
        employeeid,
        count(*) as addresscount
    FROM employee
    left join employeeaddress ON employeeaddress.employeeaddressid = employee.employeeaddressid
    group by employeeid
) counts on counts.employeeid = employee.employeeid
WHERE counts.addresscount = 0 -- Or 1, or 5 or > 1, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` should be all you need.

**[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9a89/2)**

```
SELECT  e.employeeID ,
        e.empName ,
        ea.employeeAddressID ,
        ea.addr1 ,
        ea.addr2
FROM    Employee e
        LEFT JOIN EmployeeAddress ea ON ea.employeeID = e.employeeID
```